# how to determine if an ip packet is dhcp packet

Tags: network-programming

I need to determine whether an ip packet is dhcp or not. My approach is as following

1. ipheader protocol is udp
2. upd header src and dst port is 67/68.

Is it accurate enough for determining a dhcp? 
Thanks very much

Comment: How accurate is "accurate enough"? 67 is bootps and 68 is bootpc. The most common use is UDP, but the same port numbers over TCP are also defined. There are also some ports used for DHCP failover (647), DHCP for IPv6 (546 and 547) and so on. Not clear whether you want to include those or not though.

Comment: It is accurate  enough for IPv4

Comment: Look for DHCP cookie.